replacing shortandoff{-} by xpatch parameter
I'm writing in czech with babel so there are some problems with - delimiter.
The template I'm using is changing - delimiter to an active character (as the template says) for the \cline and \cmidrule commands by lines:
\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}

I tried copying the same structure for the \hhlie command but unfortunately, it didn't work and I don't know how to proceed as I'm trying not to have to use \shortandoff command every time I want to use a tabular environment.
\xpatchparametertext\@hhline{-}{\cA-}{}{}

So, my code is:
documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
%\expandafter\let\csname ver@xpatch.sty\endcsname\empty
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@xpatch.sty}{3000/12/12}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hhline}



\makeatletter

\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@hhline{-}{\cA-}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \label{tab:1}
    \caption{Naměřené tloušťky vzorků.}
    %\shorthandoff{-}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &kabelovvý papír & komutátorový remikanit & PMMA \\
        \hline
        $h_1[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hline
        $h_2[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,00&2,03\\
        \cline{2-3} %this is here only to show it works for \cline
        $h_3[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hline
        $h_4[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,02&2,04\\
        \hline
        $h_5[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hhline{|=|=|=|=|}
        $h[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,034\\
        \hhline{|----|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

here you can see what my table looks like, there should be one line at the bottom of the table:


there is no \@hhline command what do you intend to patch?

please always post code in a form that shows the problem (missing begin document here)

Your code generate many errors. Please add missing packages (such as amsmath for \text) and the environment \begin{document}....\end{document}. By the way, you should use the siunitx package for units.

thank you both, I forgot to test it after taking it from my document.


You need to patch the commands that are defined that use -, which for hhline is \HH@loop There is no \@hhline command at all.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% only on old latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
%\expandafter\let\csname ver@xpatch.sty\endcsname\empty
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@xpatch.sty}{3000/12/12}
\usepackage{hhline}

\makeatletter%grr
\xpatchparametertext\@@@cmidrule{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\regexpatchcmd\HH@loop{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother%grr

\usepackage{amsmath}%grr
\begin{document}%grr

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \label{tab:1}
    \caption{Naměřené tloušťky vzorků.}
    %\shorthandoff{-}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &kabelovvý papír & komutátorový remikanit & PMMA \\
        \hline
        $h_1[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hline
        $h_2[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,00&2,03\\
        \cline{2-3} %this is here only to show it works for \cline
        $h_3[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hline
        $h_4[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,02&2,04\\
        \hline
        $h_5[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,03\\
        \hhline{|=|=|=|=|}
        $h[\text{mm}]$&0,10&2,01&2,034\\
        \hhline{|----|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


thank you and I'm sorry for missing pieces of my code.  I thought there is a \@hhline command as there is \@cline command. How/where can I find out which command is for which code? (like \HH@loop for hhline)?
I couldn't help but notice that you use different code to patch hhline. Can you please explain me why?

you need to look at the source code so hhline.sty in this case, I didn't have to look too hard as I wrote it, but the same principle applies, you can't simply make up the internal command name. I'm surprised regexp patch did not give an error on the undefined command but apparently not. the paramtext patch you used is for patching the "parameter text" so \def\foo#1-#2{...} the #1-#2 bit rather than the usual case (which I needed here) of doing a replace in the ... body of the definition. @JanK

So if I understand it correctly, - in cline command is parameter text and in hhline it has another attribute?

@JanK hhline tests each characer in the argument in a loop so has at one point \ifx- do something....  whereas cline just uses a - delimited argument to split the two numbers. There is no general rule, in both of these cases there was just one - to patch but in general you could need to patch any number of commands where - is used internally, and if the package code changes in any way your patches break. shorthand off is much safer.

Nice package for patching, isn't it?

@egreg shouldn't it have given an undefined error?

@egreg obviously the patching package isn't as nice as the package for adding rules to tables

You may be interested in a solution that doesn't exploit regexpatch (maybe you find some other package that wants xpatch).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
%\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{...}
%\def\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{...}

\tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl {\@cline#1-#2\@nil}
\tl_set:No \l_tmpb_tl {\@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]{#3}{#4}}
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { `- }
\exp_args:Nne \use:n { \cs_gset:Npn \@cline#1-#2\@nil } { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl }
\exp_args:Nne \use:n { \cs_gset:Npn \@@@cmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4 } { \exp_not:V \l_tmpb_tl }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { - }
\group_end:
\exp_args:NNnV \tl_replace_all:Nnn \HH@loop { - } \g_tmpa_tl
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
x & y \\
\cmidrule{2-2}
a & b \\
\cline{2-2}
a & b
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& kabelovvý papír & komutátorový remikanit & PMMA \\
\hline
$h_1$ (mm) & 0,10 & 2,01 & 2,03 \\
\hline
$h_2$ (mm) & 0,10 & 2,00 & 2,03 \\
\cline{2-3} 
$h_3$ (mm) & 0,10 & 2,01 & 2,03 \\
\hline
$h_4$ (mm) & 0,10 & 2,02 & 2,04 \\
\hline
$h_5$ (mm) & 0,10 & 2,01 & 2,03 \\
\hhline{|=|=|=|=|}
$h$   (mm) & 0,10 & 2,01 & 2,034 \\
\hhline{|----|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Thanks. What is better about using booktabs instead of regexpatch? I looked at booktabs in the past, but I don't use them because I don't share the opinion that vertical lines should not be used on tables.
of course that doesn't mean I can't use them for patching hhline command.

@JanK booktabs is completely unrelated to regexpatch. Its objective is to allow users to print better tables, which requires having no vertical line. You're free to disagree, of course. I kept booktabs and the patch to \@@@cmidrule in case somebody else, who agrees about the ugliness of vertical rules, needs the patch. In your case, you can remove the lines about \@@@cmidrule and the loading of the package.
